# CursorAdapter 's ViewBinder lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-viewbinder

Can someone help me understand `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder` lifecycle in terms of methods: `setViewValue`, `bindView` when are they called? Are instances re-used? Any source to understand all of it?

I basically have a `ScrollView` that that uses `setViewValue` to populate items but it doesn't refresh the view value even when `setViewValue` is called again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bindView is called first and later setViewValue.